# AppScript - Create a Draft Email with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose

Tags: java, google-apps-script, gmail, google-oauth

I'm trying to create an AppScript web app to create a gmail draft in the users draft inbox. I had this working using the http://www.mail.google.com scope, however, I really want to tone down the permissions to just be able to create a draft email. I tried using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose but I keep getting authorisation errors. Is there something I'm missing?

```
var forScope = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount(); // needed for auth scope

//Create Email Structure
var subject = "Email Subject";
var img = DriveApp.getFileById("Insert ID").getBlob();
var body = "<img src='cid:images' style='width:100%'><br>Test Email Content<br>"
var signature = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.filter(function(account){if(account.isDefault){return true}})[0].signature;
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var newBody = "<p>"+body+"<p>"+signature;

//Create Draft
var draft = GmailApp.createDraft("", subject, body, {htmlBody: newBody, inlineImages:{images:img}});

return;
```

Answer (score 0):

To call the `Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list()` endpoint you need one of the following scopes:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic`
- `https://mail.google.com/`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly`

The narrowest scope common to the above and the `createDraft()` endpoint is:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify`

So you can try using that instead.